# How do I get the texture to scroll on my sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a large sprite on my screen but I want the image it displays to scroll infinitely horizontally.

I have the current code which does not have any effect at all.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjLayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 0;
    public int layer = 0;
    protected Material _material;
    protected float currentscroll = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _material = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        currentscroll += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        var currentOffset=_material.GetTextureOffset("Layer3");
        _material.SetTextureOffset("Layer3", new Vector2(currentscroll, 0));
        _material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(currentscroll, 0);
    }
}
```

Just to note that I am setting both SetTextureOffset and mainTextureOffset as neither seem to be working.

Also currentOffset is changing as expected but the texture is not moving on the screen.

Comment: This is a perfect example when you should write a shader tbh

Comment: What Material are you using? Where does `"Layer3"` come from? Is this the standard unlit, or a material using a different standard Unity shader, or perhaps a self written shader? please include this info, and if it is a custom shader please include that as well. Because I'm fairly sure the standard shader doesn't have a "Layer3" property

Comment: @Menyus Why? No custom shader is needed for that, the standard Unity Unlit/Texture shader has everything needed to make it work.

Comment: @Remy Not needed indeed, but why control it from a c# script when you can do it from cg one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely using a `Material` that doesn't support texture offsetting, unless the property is `HiddenInInspector` you can check in the inspector if your material supports it by checking if it has the `Offset x,y` input fields underneath "Texture"
[image: Example of the Offset property]

The standard `Unlit/Texture` shader has this property, so do any newly created `UnlitShader`s (as seen in my example screenshot).

If you are using a custom shader then your Texture isn't named `"_MainTex"`, which is the property that Unity looks for when using `mainTextureOffset`, as cited from [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTextureOffset.html):

> By default, Unity considers a texture with the property name name "_MainTex" to be the main texture.

Using `material.mainTextureOffset` works fine for me when using a shader where the Texture is called `_MainTex`:

```cs
public Vector2 offset;
private Material material;
private void Start()
{
    material = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
}

private void Update()
{
    material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
}
```

[Result (Gyazo gif)](https://gyazo.com/ca7e7f37c78e982e9170050a4bf79ab1)

---

In your example

```cs
_material.SetTextureOffset("Layer3", new Vector2(currentscroll, 0));
```

You are looking for a property named "Layer3" in your shader, this is not a name that is standard in use by Unity (in my knowledge), if you are using a custom shader then make sure your `Texture` property has the name `Layer3` inside your shader.

---

**Update after OP's comment:**

Tiling and Offsetting is *not* available to Materials on a `SpriteRenderer`, Sprites are assumed to not be offset. As indicted by the warning given by Unity when you try to add a material that has Tiling/Ofsetting in its texture

[image: SpriteRenderer warning about Tiling/Offset]

> Material texture property _MainTex has offset/scale set. it is incompatible with spriterenderer

Instead use a Quad, Plane, Image or raw Image component which does have support for materials with tiling/offsetting in combination with the above code.

<sub>I think technically it is still possible to use offsetting with sprites by throwing on a shader that support it and ignoring the warning, but I can not guarantee this won't break down the line or what the performance implications are</sub>

Comment: I am simply using the default material used when a gameobject is created by dragging an image onto the screen. So I have a SpriteRenderer not a mesh renderer.

Comment: Thanks that is a great help. I will change my sprite to a different type.